# Whats the difference between array[index] and [array objectAtIndex:index]?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-literals

I noticed that both `array[index]` and `[array objectAtIndex:index]` work with mutable arrays. Could someone explain the difference between them? in terms of performance, and which one is the best practice?

Comment: there is not difference performance wise . it is just a difference in syntax between C and Objective C

Comment: @Osama in this case that is not C array syntax. It's modern Objective-C syntax for accessing an element from an NSArray.

Comment: The notation using `[ ]` in the "familiar" (to C programmers) way is relatively new.  There are some differences in piddlin' details between this and `objectAtIndex`, but for all intents and purposes they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None. That's part of the [clang extensions for objective-c literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), added 2-3 years ago.

Also:

> **Array-Style Subscripting**
>
> When the subscript operand has an integral type, the expression is
>   rewritten to use one of two different selectors, depending on whether
>   the element is being read or written. When an expression reads an
>   element using an integral index, as in the following example:
>
> ```
> NSUInteger idx = ...; id value = object[idx];
> ```
>
> It is translated into a
>       call to `objectAtIndexedSubscript:`
>
> ```
> id value = [object objectAtIndexedSubscript:idx];
> ```
>
> When an expression writes an element using an integral index:
>
> ```
> object[idx] = newValue;
> ```
>
> it is translated to a call to `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:`
>
> ```
> [object setObject:newValue atIndexedSubscript:idx];
> ```
>
> These message sends are then type-checked and performed just like explicit message
>   sends. The method used for `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` must be declared
>   with an argument of integral type and a return value of some
>   Objective-C object pointer type. The method used for
>   `setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` must be declared with its first argument
>   having some Objective-C pointer type and its second argument having
>   integral type.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the `array[index]` syntax resolves into a call of the `-objectAtIndexedSubscript:` method on the array. For `NSArray`, this is documented as being identical to `-objectAtIndex:`.

The subscripting mechanism can be extended to other classes (including your own). In theory, such a class could do something different for `-objectAtIndexedSubscript:` than for `-objectAtIndex:`, but that would be poor design.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Xcode 4.4, objectAtIndex: was the standard way to access array elements.
Now it can be accessed through the square-bracket subscripting syntax aswell.

Comment: It had nothing to with Xcode. It has to do with the version of clang - the Objective-C compiler. And it's not about standard array access. It's about access to objects in an NSArray.